# Score increases randomly onActionMove

Tags: java, android, andengine, sprite

when i touch finger on sprite, score increses randomly not by fix rate i mean that i set score 
to increase 50 each time but when i scroll on sprite sometimes it increases by 100 sometimes by 150 and 200;

```
       mHardware1[active] = new Sprite(pX, pY, samsung,
                this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
            @Override
            public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                    float X, float Y) {
                if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionMove()) {
                    scene.detachChild(mHardware1[active]);
                    score+50;
```

}

it works when i use isActionDown in place of isActionMove but m working a game like fruit ninja in which i need to scroll finger on screen that why i cant use isActionDown

Comment: maybe your touch is no "non-stop-movement" so you application notices several short movements where you think it is just one long movement

Comment: ya i knw this is the problm but is there any solution for this

Comment: i thought threadupdatehandler could solve this but not pls give me anys solution stackoverflow team

Answer (score 1):

You can use a SurfaceScrollDetector, which detects when the user is sliding his finger across the screen.  It has the following events associated with it:

- onScrollStarted
- onScroll
- onScrollFinished

I guess you could increase by 50 when you reach the onScrollFinished.
I am currently using the SurfaceScrollDetector for a project, but I haven't used it in a way you are asking about, so I can't say forsure if it will work as expected.

Here is one of the examples that uses it (in addition to the PinchZoomDetector):
https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/examples/PinchZoomExample.java

Comment: the problem here is i dnt want to increase score onscroll finished but  when i scroll on sprite score shuld increase

Comment: can't you just check in onScroll if your are intersecting the sprite and set a flag... then onScrollFinished, you can increase your score by 50 if the flag was set?

Answer (score 0):

Scene updates happen on a different thread to UI events, so possibly multiple queued touchscreen events are getting through before the event handler realises that the sprite has been detached.

Set a local boolean variable to prevent this, e.g.:

```
boolean touchProcessed = false;
mHardware1[active] = new Sprite(pX, pY, samsung,
            this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());

@Override
public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
        float X, float Y) {
    if (!touchProcessed & pSceneTouchEvent.isActionMove()) {
        touchProcessed = true;
        scene.detachChild(mHardware1[active]);
        score += 50;
    }
}
```

Note that you can use: `mHardware1[active].detachSelf()` instead of `scene.detachChild(...)`.

Also note that you should be detaching in the sprite in the update thread, thus:

```
boolean touchProcessed = false;
mHardware1[active] = new Sprite(pX, pY, samsung,
            this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());

@Override
public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
        float X, float Y) {
    if (!touchProcessed & pSceneTouchEvent.isActionMove()) {
        touchProcessed = true;
        score += 50;
        engine.runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 mHardware1[active].detachSelf();
             }
        });
    }
}
```